# 10 Lights (Lx), 10 Switches (Sx). S1 powers L1, S2 powers L1, L2, S10 powers L1. . .L10

Tags: pcb-design, diodes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXfG1x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to wire an educational toy for a child. If switch 1 (S1) is on, light 1 (L1) is illuminated. If switch 2 (S2) is on, light 1 (L1) and light 2 (L2) are illuminated, if switch 10 is on, lights 1, 2, . . .10 are illuminated.

I'm using 20 5v 60mA Solar Panels as the power source. 10 panels wired in parallel X 2 and those two resulting panel assemblies connected in serial. I believe that configuration should provide maximum values of 10v and 600mA.

A simple two light prototype using PCB Board showed me that I need something. With a simple wire bridge between the two circuits both lights illuminate when either switch is turned on.
[image]

Can I use a diode to between each circuit to ensure the current flow is in only one direction? I.E so that S1 on doesn't illuminate L2?

If so which diode will be needed?

Thanks for everyones interest so far. As suggested, I inserted a schematic of my initial design. I soon realized that once the current hits the PCB Boards as designed, everything lights.  Not what I want.

If I remove the PCB board and connect SW1 to D1, SW2 to D2, SWx to Dx I light the individual lights, but I want a design where if any single switch to a light is energized all the previous lights will illuminate.

Example: If SW2 state is changed, D1 and D2 will illuminate not D3.

Thanks again for your thoughts!

Comment: Click the edit button at the bottom of your question and use the built in schematic editor to draw your diagram so we don't have to guess at what your arrows mean.  Lights, switches and DC voltage sources are easy to find in there.  Where do you live?  You can't expect full output values from solar panels unless they're near perpendicular to the light source and reasonably close to the equator, so you may need to limit your expectations accordingly.  What are your lights?  LEDs?  What wattage?

Comment: Ground 1 terminal of each light. the power goes into the C of the first switch, the NO goes to the light and the C of the second switch. NO of the second switch goes to the light and C of the third switch... until you have them all connected. If switches 1,2,3,7 are on only 1,2,3 will light etc.

Comment: Another concern with panels in series/ parallel arrangements is you need to make sure they all get the same light.  A shadow over one panel in series will weaken the whole set (a lot), and in parallel you need diodes in series with the panels so that the panels in shade don't turn into loads for the panels in light.

Comment: KH Thanks for the response. I tried to use the schematic editor during creation of the original post but it doesn't work on a tablet. (doesn't support touch input) I'll have to get to a "real" computer tomorrow and create a schematic. I understand that the solar panels will not produce full power. My plan for this project is to power it with bright interior lighting.

Comment: KH  to  continue my previous response: And yes the  panels I've put together produce nowhere near the 10v maximum that the series connection could mathematically provide. The lights are LEDs and the product page shows power at 1.8W. In regards to your input concerning diodes in the solar panel connections. . .I haven't even thought of that issue. I connected the panels and had power! I thought I was golden!

Comment: Gil Thanks for your response. If I follow your recommendation, won't the circuit be wired in a series? Light 2 won't illuminate unless switch 1 and 2 are on? My desire is if switch 2 is on light 1 and 2 will be on irregardless of switch 1 position. If switch 7 is on, light 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 will illuminate irregardless of the position of switchs 1 through 6.

Comment: are you intending to SPDT toggle switches like those in the picture,  if so, there's a way to do it using only wires (no diodes)

Comment: Jason. How do I wire it with SPDT toggle switches?

Comment: draw the negative bus at the bottom, below the switches ... that will make the diagram much cleaner, and easier to understand